# Unsigned Binary Subtraction ( 0011 - 1111 = 0100 ?)

Tags: binary, subtraction, twos-complement

I'm currently building a 4-bit bitwise adder-subtractor for a project at university but the subtraction doesn't all make sense to me. I have it working for positive values `1100 - 0100 = 1000` but I'm not sure that my answer is correct when the result is negative. As can be seen in the title, when I do `0011 - 1111` for unsigned subtraction my result is `0100`. Could someone verify to me that this is the correct answer and that neither the overflow or carry should be `1` when this calculation is carried out?

Comment: If my answer correct I would be grateful if you click the tick next to my answer (top left) to show others that question has been answered sufficiently and to let the author of the question (me) know that their answer was correct

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is no. Since you are working with unsigned binary `0100` is equivalent to `4`. What might work is if you took the modulus of the returned result. To do that you could something like this

```
public class Modul {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0b0011;
        int y = 0b1111;
        int z = x - y;
        int s1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE+1;
        int s2 = s1*2;
        int finalInt = s2-z;

        System.out.println(x + "+" + y + "=" + z);

        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x) + "-" + Integer.toBinaryString(y) + "=" + Integer.toBinaryString(finalInt));
    }
}
```

This will return `1100` which is equivalent to `12`

I am unaware of why you have tagged twos-complement since you are using unsigned binary however if you want it with twos compliment you can use this little program that will return a 32 bit signed binary number

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0b0011;
        int y = 0b1111;
        int z = x - y;

        System.out.println(x + "+" + y + "=" + z);
        //3-15=-12

        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x) + "-" + Integer.toBinaryString(y) + "=" + Integer.toBinaryString(z));
        //0011-1111=11111111111111111111111111110100
    }
}
```

I believe the last four bits on this string is where you are getting `0100` from